# If $x$ does not equal $1$ then either $x$ is not a perfect square or $x+3$ is not a perfect square.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $x$ does not equal $1$ then either $x$ is not a perfect square or $x+3$ is not a perfect square. I know how to prove a perfect square but no idea on this

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**.  Suppose both are perfect squares, say $x=n^2$ and $x+3=m^2$.  Then
$$m^2-n^2=3$$
and $m,n$ are integers.  Can you do anything with this?

Answer (score 3):

If $1< x = n^2$ then $x < x+3 = n^2 + 3 = n^2 + 2(1) + 1 < n^2 + 2n + 1 = (n+1)^2$

So $x + 3$ is not a perfect square.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x=n^2$ and $x+3=m^2$. Then $3=m^2-n^2$, or $3=(m-n)(m+n)$, thus $m=2$ and $n=1$.